# 2D real-time plot with C

Tags: c, plot, 2d

I've just recently begun programming in C. I currently have an application that read's in values from a COM port and write them to a file. It reads about 500 data points per second. I want to be able to compute a real-time 2D plot of the data points with respect to time. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I've tried to post-process the data in Excel and the built in capabilities allow me to get a great graph. However, I would just like something that is computed in real-time rather than post processing it. I am using Windows XP.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about [RRDTool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KST](http://kst-plot.kde.org/) to plot your graphs in real time. You can probably keep your existing application as is (I assume you are writing to a CSV file if you are reading it in Excel) as KST will read the data from the file as it gets updated, and update its chart.

Comment: +1 for kst which does this really well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for you to explore:

1. You can use OpenGL and in particular, GLUt. I have some C code for
   this if you are interested.
2. You can pipe commands to gnuplot.
3. You can use GNU Octave from a C/C++ program. You can read more about
   this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave#C.2B.2B_integration).
4. You can create your own bitmaps in real-time of you graphs.  This isn't as hard as it sounds.

Comment: Hey Man vs. Code, yes could you please go ahead and post the C code for using GLUt? I'd like to take a look ...